# how to prevent method from overriding in java

Tags: java, excel

I have this code. Whis is searching excel csv and creating .txt file with missing subtitles for movies. One movie can have one or two or three or four subtitles. In excel it is written as Y or N for every language. It is working for one language (INDO). I added other languages (GBR,SIM,MYS) into excel and here.

```
  int INDOSUB = 4;
  int GBRSUB = 5;
  int SIMSUB = 6;
  int MYSSUB = 7;
  int KPPNAME = 1;  
  ...  
  //NEW REQUIREMENT, CHECK PLAYLIST FOR MISSING SUBTITLES
  for(int i=0; i < assets.size(); i++)
  {
      try 
      {

          file = new File(assets.get(i));
          fileReader = new FileReader(file);
          bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(fileReader);
          while((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null)
          {

              tmp = line.split(",");
              if(tmp.length > 4)
              {
                 String indosubStatus = tmp[INDOSUB];
                 String gbrsubStatus = tmp[GBRSUB];
                 String simsubStatus = tmp[SIMSUB];
                 String myssubStatus = tmp[MYSSUB];

                 String kppKey = tmp[KPPNAME];

                 if(indosubStatus.equals("N"))
                 {
                    kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey,"NO INDO SUBTITLES");
                    kppWithMissingSub.put(tmp[KPPNAME],"");
                 }

                 if(gbrsubStatus.equals("N"))
                 {
                    kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey,"NO GBR SUBTITLES");
                    kppWithMissingSub.put(tmp[KPPNAME],"");
                 }

                 if(simsubStatus.equals("N"))
                 {
                    kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey,"NO SIM SUBTITLES");
                    kppWithMissingSub.put(tmp[KPPNAME],"");
                 }

                 if(myssubStatus.equals("N"))
                 {
                    kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey,"NO MYS SUBTITLES");
                    kppWithMissingSub.put(tmp[KPPNAME],"");
                 }                                     

              }

           }

      }
      catch(IOException ex)
      {
          System.out.println(ex.toString());
      }             
  }
```

When it runs it shows only this. And I am sure KPP_Heartless is not having GBR and SIM subtitles either. But it only shows the last one. So it seems its overriding previous record.

```
KPP_HEARTLESS_19 - NO MYS SUBTITLES 

DATE/TIME: 1/11/2017 - 23:45:09:20
DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 04:45:07:21
DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 12:30:08:20
DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 17:30:04:19


KPP_LISTEN_07 - NO INDO SUBTITLES 

DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 03:30:11:24
DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 07:30:13:13
DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 15:00:10:10


KPP_LISTEN_08 - NO INDO SUBTITLES 

DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 20:00:10:05


KPP_HEARTLESS_20 - NO MYS SUBTITLES 

DATE/TIME: 1/12/2017 - 23:45:09:19
```

Does anybody know how to prevent it from overriding? Thank you very much.

Comment: How should I apply this? Because I think ..I need to check kppKey = tmp[KPPNAME] if it exist. if it exist don't override with new value but add new value. And I don't think, that I can use final for String **that was reply for somebody suggestion to use final**

Comment: They were probably confused, there is a difference between 'overriding' and 'overwriting', and you are doing the latter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It has no relation with overriding method.

The problems comes that when you write :

```
kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey,"NO SIM SUBTITLES");
kppWithMissingSub.put(tmp[KPPNAME],"");
```

you overwrite the value associated to the key.

1) If you want to have multiple values in the map, you could use a List or a Set as values. For example : `Map<String, List<String>>`.

Here is an example what you should do with the `kppSubitleMap` map but the problem is the same with `kppWithMissingSub`.

```
if(gbrsubStatus.equals("N")){
      List<String> values = kppSubitleMap.get(kppKey);
      if (values = null){
          values = new ArrayList<String>();
      }
      values.add("NO GBR SUBTITLES");
      kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey, values);
     ...
  }
```

The boiler plate code should be performed in a utility method to avoid repeat yourself in each `if` block:

```
public List<String> getOrCreateList(Map<String,List<String>> map, String key){
      List<String> values = map.get(kppKey);
      if (values = null){
          values = new ArrayList<String>();
      }
    return values;
}
```

2) If you want to simply concatenate the information you could do it :

```
String value = kppSubitleMap.get(kppKey);
if (value==null){
  value = "";
}
value += "NO GBR SUBTITLES");
kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey, value );
```

Comment: You are welcome. It was not so long for someone which discovers the concept :)

Answer (score 0):

When you invoke Map.put() several times Map contains just last value for the same key. You can use `Map<String, Set<String>>`
Example:

```
Set<String> values = kppSubitleMap.get(kppKey);
if (values == null) {
   values = new HashSet<>();
   kppSubitleMap.put(kppKey, values);
}
values.add("NO GBR SUBTITLES")
```

or use [Guava.Multimaps](https://github.com/google/guava/wiki/NewCollectionTypesExplained)